# Get data based on part of a name inside aggregate method in mongoose

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an application in which i need to check and retrieve data that have a specified name.

I have used mongoose service to perform this and the service is as follows:

```
var query = { $or: [] };
var queryAnd = { $and: [] };

queryAnd.$and.push({"Name":new RegExp("test", 'i')});
queryAnd.$and.push({$ne: ['$Value', "Deleted"]});

model.aggregate(
[
    {$project:{
        _id: '$Value',
        sValue: "$Value",
        SCount: {$cond: [queryAnd, 1, 0]}
    }},
    {$group: { _id: '$sValue', count: {$sum: '$SCount'} }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
], function (err, sResult) {
    res.send(sResult);
});
```

Here, I have used 'queryAnd' as there may be lots of 'and' and 'or' conditions.

Removing 'queryAnd.$and.push({"Name":new RegExp("test", 'i')})' gives the correct result. But i need to check the name value also. This work in find() function but not inside 'aggregate'

I have tried with following query but none worked:

```
queryAnd.$and.push({$in: ['$Name', "test"]});
queryAnd.$and.push({'Name':{$in:"test"}});
queryAnd.$and.push({"Name":{$elemMatch:{$eq:"test", $exists:true}}});
queryAnd.$and.push({ "$Name": { "$regex": "test", "$options": "i" } }]});
```

How should i get it worked.. Thanks in advance..